# Remove items from list that intersect on property using Linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have 2 lists of different objects (`foo` & `bar`) that share the same property lets call it `id`.

```
public List<foo> foo { get; set; }
public List<bar> bar { get; set; }
```

I want to remove all objects from `foo` that have an id that does not exist in `bar`

How can this be done in linq? I have been looking at `Intersect`, `RemoveAll` & `Join` but cannot find any example where the lists are of a different type.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Try this:

```
foo.RemoveAll(x=> !bar.Any(y=>y.Id==x.Id));
```

`!bar.Any(y=>y.Id==x.Id)` will get if item is in `bar` collection and if it's not it will remove it from `foo` collection.

Better solution using hashset O(n):

```
var idsNotToBeRemoved = new HashSet<int>(bar.Select(item => item.Id));                     
foo.RemoveAll(item => !idsNotToBeRemoved.Contains(item.Id));
```

source of second answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4037674/1714342

EDIT:

as @Carra said, first solution is good for small lists and second is more efficient for big lists.

Comment: For small lists, the first will do. If you're using big lists (> 100 or so), you're better of using the second solution.

Answer (score 8):

```
var foo = foo.Where(f => !bar.Any(b => b.Id == f.Id)).ToList();
```

Just keep in mind that this is a O(n²) solution, it won't work very well for big lists.

Comment: What would be a more effcient solution to this? @Carra

Comment: @ojhawkins One solution would be to pre-collect the list of `id`s from `bar` into a hashset (O(n)) then compare each element in `foo` to that (O(n)) rather than walking the `bar` list for every element in `foo`

Comment: yes I did see Jon Skeets example here but could no apply it to my example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/853526/using-linq-to-remove-objects-within-a-listt

Comment: `new HashSet<int>(bar.Select(x => x.id))` ought to do, assuming you have no collisions

Comment: Using a hashset to save your ids should work, check wudziks example.